# Getting the mean of a column using Groupby

Tags: pandas, mean

I am attempting to get the mean of the columns in a df but keeping getting this error using `groupby`

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('location')['number of orders'].mean()

print(grouped_df)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-8cc491c4c100> in <module>
----> 1 grouped_df = df.groupby('location')['number of orders'].mean()
      2 print(grouped_df)

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Comment: The code you wrote is correct. The error is exactly what it says: You did not define the DataFrame df correctly before. Could you edit your question to give us the rest of your code?

Comment: import pandas as pddef explore_df(df):
    print(df.shape[0])
    return df.head()explore_df(df_dig)

Comment: Please, edit your question, do not put unformatted code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your comment correctly, your DataFrame is calleed `df_dig`. Accordingly

```
grouped_df = df_dig.groupby('location')['number of orders'].mean()
```